# When a library my program depends depends on another library

Tags: c

When a library my program depends depends on another library, shall I specify both libraries when I compile my program with either static or dynamic linking?

When I compile my program with dynamically linking, shall I make both libraries found during loading?

Thanks.

Comment: Libraries are not supposed to be loaded at run-time. Could you differentiate between a static libray and a DLL? Probably it's useful to tell the OS, since the vocabulary depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

When your EXE depends on a DLL A you should add the import library A.lib to the linker when linking the EXE.

When your DLL A depends on DLL B you should add the import library B.lib to the linker when linking the A.DLL.

When you run the EXE both DLLs shall be available in search path.

*Edit*

Building an executable module (i.e. EXE or DLL) comprises compiling of source files and linking the compiler output with libraries to an executable.

When you consume a DLL you #include the header file that defines the interface to the DLL while compiling your sources. The import libraries of the DLLs (A.lib, B.lib) are not required here.

In the second stage of the build process the linker creates the executable module. The linker input are the compiler output, the static libraries, the import libraries of the runtime like msvcr110.dll and the import library of your A.dll.

So when I say "when linking" I mean the operation of the linker during the build process. The compiler has done it's job at this point. If you use Visual Studio you will have to add the import library A.lib to the `linker` settings of your project.

Comment: " when linking the A.DLL", do you mean during linking stage of compiling the code of A.DLL?